# Why div returns empty when web-scraping Steam Game List?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm new in web-scraping and using BeautifulSoup4, so I'm sorry if my question is obvious.

I'm trying to get the hours played from Steam, but `<div id="games_list_rows" style="position: relative">` returns None when it should return a lot of differents `<div class="gameListRow" id="game_730">` with stuff inside.

I've tried with a friend's profile who has a few games because I was thinking that working with a lot of data could make BS4 ignore the div, but it keeps showing the div empty.

Here's my code:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

# Retrieve profile
profile = "chubaquin"#input("enter profile: >")
search = "https://steamcommunity.com/id/"+profile+"/games/?tab=all"

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(search)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, "lxml")

a = soup.find("div", id="games_list_rows")

print(a)

Thanks for your help!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website is loaded dynamically, therefore `requests` doesn't support it. Try using [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) as an alternative to scrape the page.

Install it with: `pip install selenium`.

Download the correct ChromeDriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

```
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver


url = "https://steamcommunity.com/id/chubaquin/games/?tab=all"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"c:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
# Wait for the page to fully render before parsing it
sleep(5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

print(soup.find("div", id="games_list_rows"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [official Steam Web API](https://steamapi.xpaw.me/#IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames)? (xPaw docs are better than their own)

You need an API key, but they're free, and it's much easier to process the JSON result than to scrape the page(s), especially because the page can change occasionally whereas the JSON is unlikely to do so often at all.